# Too much I's in the sentence

Tags: pronouns, redundancy

I'm an Spanish-speaking person and currently learning English.

> *"I can't believe when I started this game all I thought I needed was this guide."*

Is there a better way too rephrase this so it doesn't contain multiple repetitions of the pronoun "I"? I don't want to sound selfish when it comes to expressing my own thoughts.

Comment: I suspect this is simply the typical instinct of a Spanish speaker that repeating personal pronouns sounds weird to them, since Spanish doesn't do that.

Comment: @tchrist You're right, It is weird to me. We rarely have to use the same pronoun more than once in a sentence.

Comment: *It was incredible that upon starting this game, I thought this guide sufficed!*

Answer (score 1):

You can change "when I started this game" to "when this game started," but the nature of the sentence necessitates most of the personal pronouns.

You could also change "I needed" to "I'd need" to break up the slightly awkward rhythm of having the same personal pronoun repeatedly, if that's what bothers you.